# На какой интерфейс приходят пакеты (docker)

Tags: linux, docker, администрирование, vpn, iptables

Доброго времени суток!

История такая: запустил docker контейнер с wireguard + web interface (weejewel/wg-easy) на виртуальном сервере. К ВПН подключены ноут и другие устройства.

IP адреса внутри ВПН:
Сервер - 10.8.0.1
Ноутбук - 10.8.0.2

Допустим я хочу подключится к серверу с ноутбука по ssh не по реальному IP, а по IP внутри ВПН. Как я понял TCP пакеты по этому IP идут в контейнер докера. Мне же нужно, чтобы эти пакеты (22 порт) туда не переправлялись. Как это сделать в iptables? И с какого интерфейса вообще идут пакеты (eth0 или docker0)? Надеюсь у меня получилось объяснить ситуацию и вопрос.

Iptables filter table:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
2702K 3410M DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2702K 3410M DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
1255K 2812M ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   82 10480 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
1447K  597M ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    6   384 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:51821
   10  1760 ACCEPT     udp  --  !docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           udp dpt:51820

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1447K  597M DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2702K 3410M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
1447K  597M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
2702K 3410M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Iptables nat table:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 3723  184K DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 7562  552K MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !docker0  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:51821
    0     0 MASQUERADE  udp  --  *      *       172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           udp dpt:51820

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  109  6976 RETURN     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    6   384 DNAT       tcp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:51821 to:172.17.0.2:51821
    6  1056 DNAT       udp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:51820 to:172.17.0.2:51820
```

Comment: Нет критической необходимости подключатся именно по IP адресу внутри ВПН сети, просто интересно как это реализуется, вся проблема в том, что wireguard внутри контейнера

Comment: iptables-save для более понятного вывода правил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй `172.17.0.1` чтоб подключиться к хосту.

Просто маршрутизация. Докер создает внутреннюю сеть на docker0: 172.17.0.XXX - контейнеры, 172.17.0.1 - хост.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось подключится. А как это работает? Фишка докера или что?